# Question about the position of electron and it mass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, black-holes, electrons

In order to measure the location of an electron you may use a photon, so the photon would hit the electron exactly where the electron, according to QFT. But wouldn't the mass of the electron create a black hole because then its mass would produce radius from which the photon can't escape, and that radius would be bigger than the Planck length? So my question is whether the position of the electron will be set when the photon would be very close to the electron or only when the photon actually meets the electron?

Comment: Hello! Could you please explain what leads you to the assumption that the electron would become a black hole? Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas hi, I think the fact it have mass and it exists in one point is space so it will have radius which when photon is get very close to it wouldn't be able to escape

Comment: Nice intuition. At least some professional though about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_electron